# GSON Array staying empty

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this code

```
  String link;
    link = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v3/positions/by-summoner/"+sumID+"?api_key=RGAPI-a7247558-20d7-4b0a-9009-6e3db2986a44";
    URL url = new URL(link);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    String inputLine2;
    inputLine = in.readLine();

    in.close();

    Gson code = new Gson();

    sumStatsArray[] rank = code.fromJson(inputLine,sumStatsArray[].class);
   String account = code.toJson(rank);
    //String account = code.toJson(rank.sumStats.get(0).tier) + " " + code.toJson(rank.sumStats.get(0).rank);
    System.out.println(account);
    System.out.println(link);
    System.out.println(inputLine);
```

The print account results in this : [{}]

it just stays empty, inputline contains the whole json but for somereason wont work.

sumStatsArray class looks like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class sumStatsArray {

    ArrayList<sumStats> sumStats;

}
```

and this is the json

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKeQ5.jpg

edit::looking at the code it says sumStats (right after the array list ) is never used. maybe thats the problem? I dont know how to use it though.

Comment: Is `rank` also empty ?

Comment: @Arnaud when I do String account = code.toJson(rank); and then print out account it shows up as empty. So i think so.

Comment: What does class `sumStatsArray` look like? Does it contain global variables to which Gson can map the `inputLine` String?

Comment: Could you add the code of `sumStatsArray` along with a sample JSON you receive ?

Comment: @Mark I believe I did that

Comment: @Arnaud added .

Comment: Could you try to retrieve the content of the JSON as a `sumStats[]` instead of a `sumStatsArray[]` ?

Comment: @Arnaud holy shit that worked!! can you explain to me why that worked and what I was doing wrong. Obviously I had the wrong thing but why. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well the structure of your JSON is clearly an array of a kind of object that has fields such as `tier` or `leagueId` . It couldn't be `sumStatsArray` objects because this class doesn't have those fields, but rather `sumStats` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple example to test gson.

User entity

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
        }
    }
}
```

The client code is here

```
public class GsonClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String usersJson = "[ { \"name\": \"henry\" }, { \"name\": \"justin\" } ]";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        User[] users = gson.fromJson(usersJson, User[].class);
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is like following.

`User{name='henry'}
User{name='justin'}`